# System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)");
        string qry = "INSERT INTO temporary_markers (location) VALUES ('" + txtlocation + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
```

The above snippet is what I used to pass the value to the DB. The value gets passed but "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" is whats in the table

Comment: Hi, as an upgrate please read about sqlParameters and SQL injection protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `txtlocation.Text` instead of `txtlocation`.

> `txtlocation.Text` is the string you want.
>
> `txtlocation` is your `TextBox`

Answer (score 2):

On TextBox control class Text property Gets or sets the text associated with this control so

```
 txtlocation.Text
```

gets you value on textbox.